# Populate a winform label dynamically from values in a single radlistview

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a radlistview with multiple select and checkbox enebled.

I populate the radlistview with data from an sql table using a datatable.

What i want is when i load the radlistview with my data say; Monday, Teusday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday

And i check the checkbox in the listview for Monday and Thursday, a label displays the values Monday , Thursday (separated by the coma). When i select yet another value say Friday, the value is added to make the label read, Monday, Thursday, Friday.

Am good with c# but not that good i believe. Am assuming ill have to use an array and join the values into a single string that the label will get its .Text value from.

Also note that when an existing value is disselected, say i had checked the value, Monday and then uncheck the value in the the listview,

The value 'Monday' will be removed from the label and have the label read.... Thursday, Friday.

Please note that am using vs2012 with telerik Q2 2014. I have no 'ItemChecked' event for the radlistview. I however have the event, 'ItemCheckedChanged'.

Also my radlistview values are data bound. Hope my question is explicit enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemCheckedChanged is exactly the event you need. Here is a sample code:

```
void radListView1_ItemCheckedChanged(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    string text = "";
    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in radListView1.CheckedItems)
    {
        text += item.Text + ", ";
    }
radLabel1.Text = text;
}
```